# Outputting select field with order_custom fields in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, members, custom-fields

I have a custom field called "newsletter", I've mapped this to order_custom2 from within the store settings and used the following code:

```
  <div class="control-group {if error:order_custom2}error{/if}">
    <label class="control-label" for="order_custom2">Newsletter</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {field:order_custom2} {error:order_custom2}
    </div>
  </div>
```

However it's outputting the field as a input text box rather than a select box (it was set as a select box in the member preferences) and I can't work out how to change it from a text field to a select box, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut tags provide a quick and easy way to add the field to the page but by default this will output as an input field. You do however have full control over the HTML elements and an output any form component you wish to use by simply ensuring the `name` attribute matches the name of the field. For example:

```
<div class="control-group {if error:order_custom2}error{/if}">
  <label class="control-label" for="order_custom2">Newsletter</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select name="order_custom2" id="order_custom2" >
      <option value="yes">Subscribe</option>
      <option value="no">Don't Subscribe</option>
    </select>
    {error:order_custom2}
  </div>
</div>
```

Will output a select box with whatever options you wish to provide. The `name` attribute ensures the selected value will be saved to `order_custom2`.

Comment: Was about to ask almost exactly the same question. Brilliant.